# Send email using unix mail in Elixir Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

The Phoenix Guide suggest to use SMTP provider to send emails.

I wonder if there's some Elixir library that would allow to use unix command line utility `mail` to send emails?

Comment: https://phoenixframework.readme.io/docs/sending-email This seems to indicate that they *don't* want you to use a command line mail utility, but rather suggest that you use a cloud smtp service. I've used mailgun free tier before for other projects so I'd recommend them to try out

Comment: This is clearly an offtopic here. Try https://elixirforum.com instead.

Comment: I don't know about a library for `mail` but you may find [bamboo](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bamboo) useful if you sign up for something like mailgun.